# Cannot retrieve data from JsonResult in C# and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC C# app and need to recover an object (modelview) when a specific button is clicked in the view. I managed to send the value to the JsonResult controller but I don't get back anything from it.

This is the code from the button in my razor view:

```
$("#btn-buscar").click(function (e) {
    $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: '@Url.Action(actionName: "BISSS_Modificacion", controllerName: "Home")',
             datatype: "Json",
             //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             data: { ISSS: $("#idISSSBuscar").val()},
             success: function (data) {
                 alert(data);
                 alert("todo bien  " + data.Nombres);
             }
           });
        });
```

and this is the JsonResult controller, it works since it retrieves the info

```
public JsonResult BISSS_Modificacion(string ISSS)
{
    Entity BusquedaEmpleado = new Entity();

    // here I retrieve the info from a Web API
    if (respuestaBusqueda.respuesta)
    {
        BusquedaEmpleado.NombreM = respuestaBusqueda.nombres;
        BusquedaEmpleado.ApellidoM = respuestaBusqueda.apellidos;
        BusquedaEmpleado.DUIM = respuestaBusqueda.dui;
        BusquedaEmpleado.ISSSM = respuestaBusqueda.numero_isss;
        BusquedaEmpleado.CargoM = respuestaBusqueda.cargo_participante;
        BusquedaEmpleado.SexoM = respuestaBusqueda.genero;
        BusquedaEmpleado.NivelM = respuestaBusqueda.nivel_puesto;
        BusquedaEmpleado.grupoM = Convert.ToInt32(respuestaBusqueda.grupo);

        return Json(new { BusquedaEmpleado }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }                
}
```

But when it comes to show the object in an alert window - the first alert in the click button code - this is what I get:

[image]

and if I what to show a specific value - the second alert in the click button code - this is what I get:

[image]

and if I use `console.log` to show the data, this is what I get:

[image]

Could you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

If I use `alert(JSON.stringify(data))`, I get this, which is the info I need so it looks like I getting the proper info (there are some null values but its ok):

[image]

and as you can see the prop for Apellido is ApellidoM but if I want to show that value in an alert window still got undefined -alert("todo bien  " + JSON.stringify(data.ApellidoM));

Comment: You are using `data.Nombres` but your code shows `NombreM`, which one is correct?

Comment: alert(JSON.stringify(data));

Comment: yes, I can use the intellisense in my razor view and the only prop that appears is Nombres, there is not a NombreM value to use.

Comment: IntelliSense will not show correct values unless you use JavaScript "Classes", so do not trust what it says

Comment: yes camilo you are right, just edit my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the result of the json stringify you posted, it looks like you just need to use the names of the properties that are actually on the JSON object.

```
alert("todo bien  " + data.NombreM); // todo bien  JOSE ANGER
```